# Airflow triggerdagrun operator is not running the target dag

Tags: airflow

I have 2 dags - dag a and dag b.

I have used triggerdagrun operator in dag a and passed the dag id task id and parameters in the triggerdagrun operator.

The task that triggers the second dag executed successfully and the status of dag b is running. But the task in dag b didn't get triggered. The schedule interval for dag b is none.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Is dag b paused ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you

- start the scheduler (via `airflow scheduler`)?
- enable the "dag to be triggered" (per default DAGs are paused)?

... both are necessary conditions such that tasks get run...